# Counting items in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I count how many items have in each category. I use this to show them.

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  id, name FROM cat_gif ORDER BY name");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
            echo '<div id="cat"><a href="gif_cat.php?id='. $res['id'] .'">&raquo '.$res['name'].'</div></a><br/>';
        }
```

I know I can use `COUNT` but I don't know where and how to use it.

update:
Table `cat_gif` rows are

```
id
name
```

Table gifs rows are

```
id
caption
name
size
type
file_path
gif_cat
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY category`

Comment: Instead of `ORDER BY`? How this help me to count items?

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` having lots of difference...`ORDER BY` use for  display data order wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it

```
        $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT gif_id, gif_name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gifs WHERE gifs.gif_cat = gif_id) AS count FROM cat_gif ORDER BY gif_name");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {

            echo '<div id="cat"><a href="gif_cat.php?gif_id='. $res['gif_id'] .'">&raquo '.$res['gif_name'].' ('.$res['count'].') </div></a><br/>';
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `count(name)` with `GROUP BY name` in your query as follows which gives you count for each categroy

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT   name, count(name) as cnt FROM cat_gif GROUP BY name");
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $count = $res['cnt']; // your count  
    $name = $res['name']; // your category name

    echo "Category Name : ".$name." --> ".$count."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't count correctly. Show on every category --> 1

Comment: In which table? `cat_gif` or `gif` ?

Comment: in which you count your category.

Comment: In `cat_gif` and when I upload gif I store `id` of category in `gif_cat` row in `gifs` table. Check my question I updated with table info

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT category, count(id) FROM cat_gif GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
SELECT  count(name) FROM cat_gif group by __your_category_column__;
```

replace **your_category_column** with actual name of the column.

Answer (score 1):

count rows like

```
$row_cnt = $q->num_rows;
```

for more info https://www.php.net/mysqli_num_rows

also you can use `count()`

```
SELECT category, count(id) FROM cat_gif GROUP BY category
```

Comment: Same like @Satish answer gave me on all category '1' even in category has more than 1 item..

Comment: `$row_cnt = $q->num_rows;` count the numbers of category not numbers of items in each category.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,

```
SELECT category_name, COUNT(id) FROM cat_gif GROUP BY category_name;
```

Please use the category name in the category_name(i.e., the column name).

Answer (score 1):

**Use this. it's would works sure.**

```
SELECT category, count(id) FROM cat_gif group by category;
```